# Cant get Value out of HTML with document.getElementById();

Tags: javascript, html

i am new to JavaScript and not the best at HTML but have to do the following for school:
I found a Stopwatch HTML-Code and i made a javascript for it, which shall calculate the laborunits(LU) out of the stopped time.
1 LU = 15 minutes (900 seconds)
The problem is, that i cant get the stopped time from the HTML-Site into my JavaScirpt, to calculate the "LU".

I tried document.getElementById and document.getElementsByClassName

with document.getElementsByClassName i always get something like "**object htmldivelement**"
and with document.getElementById all the variables stay null and i cant figur out, how i can fix that.
do i need to use some other command or what am i doing wrong?

```
<div class="container">
        <!-- controls -->
        <input id="start" name="controls" type="radio" />
        <input id="stop" name="controls" type="radio" />
        <input id="reset" name="controls" type="radio" />

        <div class="timer">
                <div class="cell">
                        <div class="numbers tenhour moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                        <div class="numbers hour moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell divider"><div class="numbers">:</div></div>
                <div class="cell">
                        <div class="numbers tenminute movesix">0 1 2 3 4 5 6</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                        <div class="numbers minute moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell divider"><div class="numbers">:</div></div>
                <div class="cell">
                        <div class="numbers tensecond movesix">0 1 2 3 4 5 6</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                        <div class="numbers second moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell divider"><div class="numbers">:</div></div>
                <div class="cell">
                        <div class="numbers milisecond moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                        <div class="numbers tenmilisecond moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                        <div class="numbers hundredmilisecond moveten">0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var ae;
var zs = document.getElementById('cell');
var es = document.getElementById('cell');
var zm = document.getElementById('cell');
var em = document.getElementById('cell');
var zsek = document.getElementById('cell');
var esek = document.getElementById('cell');
document.write("<center><h2>Erfasste AEs: </h2></center> <h2>");

document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function() {
    zs = zs * 36000;
    es = es * 3600;
    zm = zm * 600;
    em = em * 60;
    zsek = zsek * 10;
    ae = ((zs + es + zm +em + zsek + esek) / 900) + 1;
    document.write(ae);
};
```

If the stop-button is pressed it shall tell me the calculated
LaborUnits. the problem that if the Stop-Button is pressed, the
JavaScript posts the answer on a "new" blank site, will i try to
solve.

i would appreciate every kind of help and sorry for my patchy english

Comment: can you put this in a js fiddle / code pen site , as not able to get requirement clearly

Comment: `document.getElementById('cell');` won't work because you don't have any elements with `id="cell"` in your HTML. You only have elements with `class="cell"`. But even if that retrieved an element, it would make no sense because you can't tell which one is which. If each element contains a value with a specific meaning then you need a way to identify them, so it would make more sense to give each element a _unique_ id, and then get each one by its unique ID. Also, the actual values appear to be contained with an element inside that outer "cell" element anyway, so you need to target that instead

Comment: Well cell is a class so id is not going to work since it is not an id. Now ids need to be singular so you can not have more than one. So why are you not using ids for each part? id="second", id="minute"? Or you do have classes with each part so you can do `var milisecond = document.querySelector(".milisecond");`

Answer (score 0):

Start by giving your cells unique ids. Right now you're trying to reference their class. Even if you changed this class designation to id, you wouldn't get the values you expect because they would all share the same id.

```
<div class="cell">
  <div class="numbers tensecond movesix" id="tensecplace">0 1 2 3 4 5 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to put the ID on the inner element where the actual data is held?